# How do I change the saturation of my background terrain depending on its distance from my player object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object that moves around a terrain.

I want the places it visits to be lit up when the object approaches is and become dark again when it leaves that area.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: My oracle machine give me the output "not enough information".

Comment: If you have shading routines in place then use your object as a light source